# Why Next Js Default router is Not working?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

default router is not working even though when i use correct folder structure in version 13.5.4 next Js.

Simply i created the new project using the command like **npx create-next-app@latest project name** and inside the App folder created the folder called **user**.Inside the user folder created the **about.js** file.but it shows the **404 page** when i use the url **(http://localhost:3000/user)** I don't know why?.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ITUk.png)

[404 error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyFfO.png)

Answer (score 1):

When using the "app folder" for Next, your pages need to be actually called "page.js" (or "page.jsx" or "page.tsx")

So if you wanted to access the user page at `localhost:3000/user`, your directory structure should be:

```
app/
  user/
    page.js
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params